# Filter the JSON data based on ID - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
'products': [{  // List of productFieldObjects.
    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     
    'item_id': '12345',
    'item_price': '15.00',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'variant': 'Black',
    'quantity': 1, 
    'something' : 'anc',
    'something2' : 'xyz',
    'something3' : 'yyy'                     
   },
   {
    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
    'item_id': '12345',
    'item_price': '15.00',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'variant': 'Black',
    'quantity': 1,
    'something' : 'anc',
    'something2' : 'xyz',
    'something3' : 'yyy'
   },
   {
    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
    'item_id': '12345',
    'item_price': '15.00',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'variant': 'Black',
    'quantity': 1,
    'something' : 'anc',
    'something2' : 'xyz',
    'something3' : 'yyy'
   }
```

]

The following data has to be filtered out.

```
'products': [{
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',       
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '45.00',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Black'
        'quantity': 3
       }]
```

Filter the data from the array and return the single array object if it matches with ID. If there are 3 items quantity and price should be added as well

Current Code

```
var filter = products.filter(function(items){
                    if(items.id == products.id){
                      return items;
                    }
                })
```

How can I make this please guide thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Do you need to filter out based on ID or do some calculations on it?

Comment: `filter` is not what your looking for in this case because you want to modify elements within given array. I think you should give `reduce` a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with object destructuring to only select the required key, to create an object with id as key and object as the value using all the extracted values, for the same key add quantity. Then extract out all values from this object using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = {'products': [{ 'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt', 'item_id': '12345', 'item_price': '15.00', 'brand': 'Google', 'category': 'Apparel', 'variant': 'Black', 'quantity': 1,'something' : 'anc','something2' : 'xyz','something3' : 'yyy' }, { 'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt', 'item_id': '12345', 'item_price':'15.00', 'brand': 'Google', 'category': 'Apparel', 'variant': 'Black', 'quantity': 1,'something' : 'anc','something2' : 'xyz','something3' : 'yyy' }, { 'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt', 'item_id': '12345', 'item_price': '15.00', 'brand': 'Google', 'category': 'Apparel', 'variant': 'Black', 'quantity': 1,'something' : 'anc','something2' : 'xyz','something3' : 'yyy' } ]},
  result = Object.values(data.products.reduce((r,{name,item_id: id,item_price: price,brand = '',category = '', variant = '', quantity}) => {
    r[id] = r[id] || {name,id,brand,category,variant, price: 0, quantity: 0};
    r[id].price += +price;
    r[id].quantity += quantity;
    return r;
  },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have item_price and want to return price key

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: It is saying `undefined` because you don't have brand, category and variant in your object.

Comment: the only thing remain that does not calculating price pls update too thanks

Comment: Updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `condense()` `function` below traverses the `array` in its `params` to group `products` by `id` and update their `quantity` and `price` values accordingly until a condensed `array` of `products` is finally `returned`.

See [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for more info.

```js
// Products.
const input = [
  {  
    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     
    'id': '12345',
    'price': '15.00',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'variant': 'Black',
    'quantity': 1,                      
  },
  {
    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
    'id': '12345',
    'price': '15.00',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'variant': 'Black',
    'quantity': 1
  },
  {
    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
    'id': '12345',
    'price': '15.00',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'variant': 'Black',
    'quantity': 1
  }
]

// Condense.
const condense = (products) => Object.values(products.reduce((total, product) => {
  const {id} = product
  const existing = total[id]
  if (existing) {
    const quantity = parseFloat(existing.quantity) + parseFloat(product.quantity)
    const price = (quantity * parseFloat(product.price)).toFixed(2)
    return {
      ...total, 
      [id]: {
        ...existing,
        quantity,
        price
      }
    }
  }
  return {...total, [id]: product}
}, {}))


// Proof.
const output = condense(input)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: //appreciated your time im in confusion thats good but it return id then object i do not wants so also get ride the key something, something1, something2 value just need to be clear key value it expected result

Comment: See my udpated question pls

Comment: return for me 12 : {
   'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
        'id': '12345',
        'item_price': '15.00',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Black',
        'quantity': 1,
        'something' : 'anc',
        'something2' : 'xyz',
        'something3' : 'yyy'
}....

Comment: should be only [
  {
    "name": "Triblend Android T-Shirt",
    "id": "12345",
    "price": "45.00",
    "brand": "Google",
    "category": "Apparel",
    "variant": "Black",
    "quantity": 3
  }
]

Comment: I need to transform the data from whole key values to expected key value

Comment: How is the `output` from the snippet above different to your `expected result`?